# Foreign key on post request Laravel & Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, axios

I am using a larvel backend with a vue frontend. They are connected by API. I have been trying to figure out how i can correctly submit a form for a model that has a `foreign_key` relationship with a parent model.

Here is the relationships

1. A User has many Tasks
2. A Task belongs to User
3. A Client has many Engagements
4. A Engagement belongs to Client
5. Engagements and Tasks have many to many
6. User and Client have no direct relationship

So I know that if i wanted to submit a post request for data that had a relationship with user It would be simple to assign the foreign_key like below

*Example

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'completed' => 'required|boolean',
        ]);
        $todo = Todo::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'title' => $request->title,
            'completed' => $request->completed,
        ]);
        return response($todo, 201);
    }
```

But when i try to do this same thing for my client I get a 500 internal server error..

So here is the Workflow

On my vue frontend in the AddEngagment.vue component

```
<template>
  <div class="page-wrapper mt-1">
    <div class="add-engagement container">
      <div class="card-body bg-light border-primary mb-2">
        <h4 class="text-left text-primary m-0"><i class="mr-3 far fa-folder-open"></i>New Engagement</h4>
      </div>
        <form @submit.prevent="addEngagement" class="d-flex-column justify-content-center">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control mb-3" id="type" v-model="engagement.return_type">
              <option v-for="type in types" :key="type.id" :value="type">{{ type }}</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Year" v-model="engagement.year">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Assign To" v-model="engagement.assigned_to">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Status" v-model="engagement.status">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary d-flex justify-content-start">Create</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'add-engagement',
  data() {
    return {
      engagement: {
        return_type: null,
        year: '',
        assigned_to: '',
        status: '',
      },
      types: [ 
        'Choose Return Type...', 
        '1040', 
        '1120',
      ],
    }
  },
   methods: {
    addEngagement(e) {
      if(!this.engagement.return_type || !this.engagement.year ){
        return
      } else {
        this.$store.dispatch('addEngagement', {
          id: this.idForEngagement,
          return_type: this.engagement.return_type,
          year: this.engagement.year,
          assigned_to: this.engagement.assigned_to,
          status: this.engagement.status,
        })
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      this.engagement = "" 
      this.idForEngagement++
      this.$router.push('/engagements')
    },
  },
  created: function() {
    this.engagement.return_type = this.types[0]
  },

}
</script>
```

I am capturing the data in the input and then dispatching the store for the addEngagement action

Now in the URL for the AddEngagement.vue component I have the client_id shown like below

```
add-engagement/{client_id}
```

This is the store.js action for the addEngagement

```
addEngagement(context, engagement) {
      axios.post(('/engagements'), {
        return_type: engagement.return_type,
        year: engagement.year,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
        done: false
      })
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('getClientEngagement', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

So from here, it sends the request to my /engagement on the laravel api route file like below

```
Route::post('/engagements', 'EngagementsController@store');
```

And then goes to the EngagementsController to run the store method below

```
public function store($client_id, Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'return_type' => 'required|string',
            'year' => 'required|string',
            'status' => 'required|string',
            'assigned_to' => 'required|string',
            'done' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);

        $engagement = Engagement::create([
            'return_type' => $request->return_type,
            'year' => $request->year,
            'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'done' => $request->done,
            + [
                'client_id' => $client_id
            ]
        ]);

        return response($engagement, 201);
    }
```

At this point is where I am getting my error and I think it has to do with the `$client_id` which I have tried many different ways of formatting it with no success. When the URL is storing the `client_id` on the front end for the post request I do not know how that data is getting shared with laravel for it to know which client the `client_id` foreign key will be assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
$engagement = Engagement::create([
            'return_type' => $request->return_type,
            'year' => $request->year,
            'assigned_to' => $request->assigned_to,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'done' => $request->done,
            + [
                'client_id' => $client_id
            ]
        ]);
```

why is there this `+[...]` array thing? Doesn't really makes sense to me...

But the 500 Server Error most probably results from your false request (which most of 500's do).

If this is your Route definition:

```
Route::post('/engagements', 'EngagementsController@store');
```

This is the method head:

```
public function store($client_id, Request $request)
```

And your Post request is the following:

```
axios.post(('/engagements'), {
        return_type: engagement.return_type,
        year: engagement.year,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
        done: false
      })
```

You will notice, that the function definition differs from your Route. In the function you expect a parameter 'client_id' which isn't known by the route. So to resolve this issue, put your client_id into the Post request body (underneath your done: false for example) and remove the parameter from the function definition.